# Logitech Wingman Gaming Mouse on WIndows 7

Tags: windows-7, drivers, logitech-mouse

Windows 7 does not recognize my old Logitech Wingman Gaming Mouse.

Hence it does not send mousbutton-messages for the **middle button** (left and right button are working with the default driver).

I don't expect Logitech to do anything about it.

Question: Is there a generic **mousedriver available**, which could be adapted to the WIngman mouse (by configuring or programming or both)?

Answer (score 0):

There is an input driver "hook" that I have tested, and it is helping other people with older items that the manufactures will not support. 
It is called [Xmousebuttoncontrol](http://www.highrez.co.uk/downloads/XMouseButtonControl.htm)

This will provide for 3, 4, 5 button mouses using the standard compatibility or for Microsoft Intellipoint mouse drivers, plus an array of other things like per program configurations, and hotkeys and all.

Then Windows 7 might drop-out the low level hook if it delays for too long, or if some other thing causes a delay, so there is this registry location.

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop]

"LowLevelHooksTimeout"=dword:00002710
```

At this location the timeout for hooks (general) can be altered.

*IMPORTANT*: The number that is there is not tested by me.  It will have to be tested and set as you need it. The number should be considered a placeholder or example.

Because it is *NOT* a Driver, this is *NOT* an answer.
I think there are some creative crossing up by using other "new" drivers and getting them to work with Old stuff, but I have not got that far yet.